# HERE Maps Truck Api

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I have a truck routing API call for HERE maps. It splits the section into 3 parts including ferry section. However, I want to avoid receiving the route if route for the specified transport Mode is not available for HERE Routing API version 8.6.4 . Is there any parameter we can pass to avoid getting ferry route if truck is specified as transport mode?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you saying you call the API and it returns a part that isn't available?

Comment: If you just want to avoid ferry, you can try add "&avoid[features]=ferry" to your API call. Please let us know if this will work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If i i add avoid ferry, it gives me the route with ferry with a notification that this route will violate the restrictions.However, I don't want any route if it involves any other mode of transport.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike V7, V8 routing only supports "soft" avoid.

"Sometimes no route is possible that avoids the feature, for example specifying avoid[features]=ferry to an otherwise inaccessible island. In this case, a route is returned that makes minimal use of the feature. Furthermore, a notice is included to indicate that the route does not avoid the feature."

For details, you make check [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/8.6.4/dev_guide/topics/use-cases/avoid.html).

Comment: It appears appending avoid[features]=ferry results in a "missing waypoints" error even when they are present.  See bug here:

No error: https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey=API_KEY_GOES_HERE&waypoint0=geo!44.648077,-63.571564&waypoint1=geo!46.329902,-62.362851&mode=fastest;car

With error: https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey=API_KEY_GOES_HERE&waypoint0=geo!44.648077,-63.571564&waypoint1=geo!46.329902,-62.362851&mode=fastest;car&avoid[features]=ferry